Counter Example for the Resolvent of a Strongly Monotone Operator being Strongly Monotone
With $B: \mathcal H \mapsto 2^{\mathcal H} := A + \beta I$, $\beta > 0$, $A: \mathcal H \mapsto 2^{\mathcal H}$ being maximal monotone, $B$ is strongly monotone.
Consider $\mathcal J_B = (I + B)^{-1}$.
It's not directly evident whether $\mathcal J_B$ is strongly monotone.
Is there a strongly monotone operator $B$ such that $\mathcal J_B$ is not strongly monotone?
I just thought about it one day and failed to identify good examples to support it.
Here is what is known:

$I - \mathcal J_B$ is $1 - (1 + \beta)^{-1}$ strongly monotone.
$\mathcal J_B$ is $(1 + \beta)^{-1}$ Lipschitz.
$\mathcal J_B$ firmly non-expansive for sure.


Let $\mathcal H$ be Hilbert space.
Do
$$
A : \mathcal H \mapsto \mathcal H = \text{diag}(1, 2, 3, ...)
$$
So resolvent $(I + A)^{-1} = \text{diag}(1/2, 1/3, 1/4, \cdots)$.
Now let $x_n = \mathbf e_n$, $y = \mathbf 0$, $\beta > 0$, the sequence of the standard basis vector and the zero vector.
Then do:
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \langle x_n - y, \mathcal J_A x_n - \mathcal J_A y\rangle
    &= 
    \langle \mathbf e_n, \mathcal J_A  \mathbf e_n\rangle 
    \\
    &= 1/(n + 1), 
    \\
    \implies 
    \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 
    \langle x_n - y, \mathcal J_A x_n - \mathcal J_A y\rangle
    &= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}1/(n + 1)
    = 0 \not\ge \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \beta\Vert \mathbf e_n\Vert = \beta > 0, 
\end{aligned}
$$
which is contradicting the definition of strong monotonicity for $\mathcal J_A$.
